# How to load .PHTML Files

Tags: magento2

So i have worked out this bit of code here

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
  <arguments>
     <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
```

Is giving me Compare Products My Account My Wish List Create an Account Sign In, That's great but what i am now trying to do is to get them outside of

```
div class="page-wrapper"

header class="page-header"

div class="header content"
```

I cannot work out how to get them out, Any ideas would help me out a lot all.

Many Thanks

Edit

Ive worked out how to get them outside now but they wont show in order. Inside of my home.xml i have this

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">  
    <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
     <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
    <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
</referenceContainer>
```

But that shows in the html as

div class="page-wrapper"
div class="topbar"

So its the wrong way around im going to go back through the manuals but i can't remember seeing how to sort this.

Comment: are you referring to take top links out or do you need to insert selected top link any other place rather than top links ?

Comment: the standard toplinks, ive managed to get them into there own DIV now but they only display at the very bottom of the page i cannot get them to the top

Comment: CHeck your toplinks block is inside <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your question clearly but please check below links may be it helps you :

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-practice.html

http://www.dckap.com/blog/add-custom-header-footer-links-magento-2/